# Wear OS app in Play Console - target API error

Tags: android, publish, wear-os, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I have an Wear OS app on the Play Store. Recently I wanted to upload update but I'm getting error `Your app currently targets API level 30 and must target at least API level 31 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 31`.

I would understand this for regular phone app but in Play Console Help Center they clearly state that Wear OS app are excluded (since nothing newer than API 30 exists there anyway) - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878

This is the error:
[image: target API error]

I'm not sure how they define (distinguish) between regular app and Wear OS app because when I've created store listing it was basically regular app setup + enabling Wear OS form factor but all the documentation describe it this way. And the distribution was working fine so I consider my app listing Wear OS only.
[image]

I also have `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />` in the manifest as required.

Tldr; is it something I'm missing in my setup to be eligible for this target API exception for Wear OS or is this console error happening to others as well?

Comment: I got the same problem....

Answer (score 0):

**Change Your targetSdkVersion to 31**

*then try to Upload on Play Consol*
[image]

Comment: Yes, updating target version would work but makes no real sense for Wear OS app since API 30 is the latest Wear OS out. I was looking for a solution without increasing target version (as it should work according to docs).

Comment: Actually play not accepting target 30 any more. if answer is helpful give me upvote and accept answer. thanks

Comment: You shouldn't update your App to 32, per https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878, Wear is still on 30. But if you can't get them to approve, it probably unblocks you.

Comment: @KamranKhan nope it is not correct answer at least it shouldn't be. Look at the original link I've posted and also here https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk For Wear OS target should be API 30 even after November '22.